# python facebook. posting to main page feed as admin, not to left bottom feed

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token, facebook-permissions

I wanna ask comunity for any help with facebook page posting.

I have page managed by my account. I can post any info to page main feed in the center. When users posts to my page, their messages displays in he visitor feed in top bottom corner of the page.

Now i need to auto post news with access token linked to page owner's account  from python app. I'm using long-lived access token (has no perms such as manage_pages, publish_actions, publish_pages) and it posts to my page successfully (seems because i'm admin of the page), but not to main feed, only to visitor feed.

How to solve such issue? Thanks.

Regards

Comment: You need to use a page access token. (And if you don’t know how to get that, or even what it is – read the documentation on access tokens.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My FB permissions still on review, but after reading the docs and googling i founded the way how to get never-expired token just for use by  yourself. e.g.

https://www.rocketmarketinginc.com/blog/get-never-expiring-facebook-page-access-token/